# Send Notification to other users and other users have the option to accept or reject it

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification, notifications

I am building an Android app and i am using Firebase as the database to store users and more. My requirement is that i need users to click on a button and send notifications to other users(typically they will be 2-3 users). When other users receive the notification they should have the option to "accept" it or "reject" the request. If they click to accept it the sender of the notification should get notified (just a notification) as well as the admin users. 
I have found online several options on how to send notifications with FCM or using a third party server but the tricky part that i haven't found is how will they accept or reject a notification? Has anyone done something similar or can someone direct me to a solution that would satisfy this requirement(accept and reject a notification)?

Comment: Insided onReceiveMessage method of in your android app , parse message ---> show popup or notification to the user --> accept or reject --> based on the selection send the notification to the originator of the message/notification.

Comment: @cousma I am trying to do something similar. Can you let me know if you were able to do this and what was the approach you used.